# Math calculator script error with JS

Tags: javascript, html

did I miss something with my script?

its like everything goes right when I press the minus (-) button, but when i press plus (+) button the calculator goes wrong. its show 1, 11, 21, ~ everything was end with 1..

here is my code :

```js
function myFunctionDown() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x-y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(-1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
function myFunctionUp() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x+y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
<button onclick="myFunctionUp()">+</button>
<br/><br/>
$ <span id="demo">0</span>
```

I got this code from w3school and edit it in very basic knowledge. Is there anything I miss? or do you have any better ways to write it corectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the input value to a number - since all input values are actually strings.

```js
function myFunctionDown() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x-y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(-1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
function myFunctionUp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x+y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
<button onclick="myFunctionUp()">+</button>
<br/><br/>
$ <span id="demo">0</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

Use `parseInt()` function to convert string value into Number type.

```js
function myFunctionDown() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x-y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(-1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
function myFunctionUp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x+y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
<button onclick="myFunctionUp()">+</button>
<br/><br/>
$ <span id="demo">0</span>
```

Comment: Actually there's no `Integer` type in JavaScript, it should be `Number` instead.

Comment: @chŝdk well said..!!! will be number instead of integer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the string an integer/number (it is currently a string so it is concatenating the value rather than adding it). You can do this by using `parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);`

This will make the value into an integer, for example `"1"` into `1`

```js
function myFunctionDown() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x-y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(-1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
function myFunctionUp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x+y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
<button onclick="myFunctionUp()">+</button>
<br/><br/>
$ <span id="demo">0</span>
```

Comment: It should be `Number` and not `Integer` in your first sentence, *You need to make the number an integer* should be  *you need to parse strings as Number*.

Comment: @chŝdk Ah, thanks ha ha. Updated it :)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to convert the input value to `Number` and no need to multiply it by 1. Use `parseInt` function for the conversion.

```
<button onclick="myFunctionDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
<button onclick="myFunctionUp()">+</button>
<br/><br/>
$ <span id="demo">0</span>
<script>
function myFunctionDown() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = x-y;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(-1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
function myFunctionUp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
    var y = 1;
    var a = x+y;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Same thing, there's no `Integer` type in JavaScript, it should be `Number` instead.

Comment: Ah yes. It should be Number type. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Do `+document.getElementById("myNumber").value`. Problem solved.

**Reason:**

- By definition `document.getElementById("myNumber").value` returns *String* value in x
- JS has an urge to prevent the compiler errors. So, while doing `x+y` i.e. `Number + String`. JS, by default, automatically typecast your *Number* value to string and interprets '+' as the concatenation operator.

You can use the same urge of JS in your favour. When, JS tackles a '+' sign before a string and if that string is nothing but numeric characters. It gets converted into number.

Refer [Addition Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()) and [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) for details.

```js
function myFunctionDown() {
    var x = +document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x-y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(-1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
function myFunctionUp() {
    var x = +document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = 1;
    var a = (x+y)*1;
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
<button onclick="myFunctionUp()">+</button>
<br/><br/>
$ <span id="demo">0</span>
```